# Use the same resources for multiple locales

Tags: android, resources, locale

I have to translate an app in hebrew.

All my unlocalized ressources (drawable, values, etc) are for english.
Hebrew is 'he', so I have some folders like drawable-he, values-he
but could be 'iw' on some phones.

Is there a way to force 'iw' phones to use the 'he' folders ?
For now the only solution I found is to duplicate all my resources folders with -iw, 
but my app became bigger obviously.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean to say, you want to use particular language folder at some point in your code? I am not able to understand your ques. Please, explain this thing  as I asked?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is alias resources. You still need a separate folder for each locale but you do not need to duplicate resources.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Answer (score 1):

Aliases works only with strings and drawable, not with raw, but the raw data usualy is big, so alias do not solve the problem.

Another solution is to put Hebrew data in default folders, and english data in values-en, drawable-en, raw-en folders, so duplication will be eliminated, but this way all other languages that was not defined explicitly will see Hebrew instead of English.